# GMP (GNU Multiple Precision) : "mpz_mod" function error

Tags: c++, function, modulo, gmp

Can anyone help me with this?
The function "mpz_mod" is wrong but i don't know how to fix it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <gmpxx.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
   mpz_class p;
   mpz_class y;
   mpz_class m;
   for ( p=100 ; p<=500 ; p=p++)
      {
         for ( y=50 ; y<=60 ; y=y++)
            {
               mpz_mod (m,p,y);
            }
          if (m==0)
          cout << p << "," << y << "  ok  " <<endl;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mpz_mod` is for C code, and takes `mpz_t *` as arguments.  Since you're using C++ and `mpz_class`, you want `m = p % y;`

Comment: I want to use a function for mod (%) but from the gmp library.What can i do?

Comment: `%` is overloaded by the gmp library to work on `mpz_class` objects, so by using `%` you are getting the mod function from the library.

Comment: Is there any faster function for mod?

Comment: In your case, since your numbers are all small, you could use `int` instead of `mpz_class` and not use the GMP lib at all.